# How to make 'mail' command work properly via SSH?

Tags: shell, ssh, mailx

When logged into my server via SSH the `$ mail` command doesn't work properly.  Instead of returning the list of mail it returns `No mail for <user>`.

`$ mail` works correctly when on a terminal at the machine, so it's definitely an issue with using SSH, which is how I will need to access it.

Comment: What is the `ssh` command that you're using?

Comment: @schaiba, I'm just accessing the server like `ssh user@server` and then running the mail command at the prompt.  `$ mail`.

Comment: What is the value of `$MAIL` in each case?

Comment: @JigglyNaga, this seems to be the problem.  when logged in via SSH (even as regular user) the path is set to `/var/spool/mail/root`.  Via the actual console it is `/var/spool/mail/alxs`.

Comment: something is incorrectly setting $MAIL, then

Comment: I edited the question for clarity.  Not sure why someone has down voted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to correctly read user mails by giving in input the file path:

```
mail -f /var/spool/mail/$USER
```

I also encountered some issue reading (root)user email, I ssh logged in with user phil, then I changed user to root typing `sudo su` and then issuing `mail` command I got:

> No mail for phil

So it seems that mail command try to read the email of the user with whom you opened the ssh connection. And as it came out the cause is a wrong value of `$MAIL` variable:

```
[root@preprod ~]# echo $MAIL
/var/spool/mail/phil
```

Comment: Cheers @lese, That's what's happening.  It's just a VM so I'm logging in as root and then su to a regular user.  So the environment remains set from the original login.  Thanks mate!

Comment: You need to use 'su - <user>'. That sets all the user's environment variables correctly

Comment: Yeah `sudo - <user>` correctly sets the environment variables.  I'll get into the habit of doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

try using `sudo su -` the '-' would allow the profile and environment variable to be set for user you are switching to which would then allow the mail command to run as expected.

Note: It will be for all environment variables and not just $MAIL.

Comment: Thanks Kerbi.  I'll get into the habit of doing it this way!  Up-voted. :)